# PHP - Parse Json

Tags: php, json

I have an answer in json, but how can I parse?

Response: (var_dump)

```
C:\wamp64\www\PHP\index.php:17:
object(stdClass)[1]
  public 'success' => boolean true
  public 'data' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[2]
          public 'key' => string '11111-11111-11111-11111-11111' (length=29)
          public 'allowed_acts' => int 1
```

I tried this code, but dont works

```
if ($keys) {

$json = json_decode($keys);

//$dump = var_dump($json);

//echo $dump;

echo $json['key'];
}
```

Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\wamp64\www\PHP\index.php on line 21

Comment: Have you tried `echo $json->key;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already parsed response. Please note that in your response `var_dump` result you have

```
object(stdClass)[1]
```

which means it's already na object.

You can access its content with `->` operator.

E.g. to get `key` value, you should try with:

```
echo $result->data[0]->key;
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked like a charm. Many thanks for the explanation ...